# Compression fitting with copper nut and plastic pipe keeps leaking

Tags: plumbing, humidifier

I have a problem with a compression fitting leaking for the water supply of my new humidifier. The connection includes a copper nut and ferrule and plastic tubing. There is a slow drip at the connection that I cannot get to stop. I’m afraid of over tightening. After the first try did the same thing and I DID over tighten, I cut the plastic tube square, used a new ferrule and tried again tightening very slowly. At this point I’m not sure I’d i need to continue tightening or if there’s another problem. Help!

Comment: The ferrel bends, it's a one-shot part of the fitting.  99% of the time it must be replaced evertime you disconnect the tubing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With plastic pipe compression fittings usually come with an insert made of metal or hard plastic.  The compression nut and ferrule (generally plastic for plastic pipe) is placed over the pipe, then the insert is pushed into the end of the pipe.  When the joint is tightened the insert prevents the plastic pipe from collapsing as the ferrule bites in.  Without the insert it is very difficult to make a compression connection in plastic watertight.

See the second question in the FAQ on this page: https://www.plumbingsupply.com/ed-compression.html

Comment: Ahhhhhh. I definitely didn't put an insert in. I believe there was one in the kit but it wasn't referenced in the install manual. Thank you!

Comment: If the above resolves the issue please mark the question answered.